# High ranking at global leaderboards of Civ5 BNW

Tags: civilization-5-brave-new-world

High rankings at the global leaderboards have many mysteries.
For example, current #1 is Russian tech victory at turn 11 of Diety.
But tech victory needs building spaceship which needs quite latest tech. But how can he/she reach such level at turn 11?

Current #2 is Moroccan domination victory at turn 0 of Diety.
But domination victory needs occupation of all other's capitol.
How can he/she do that?

Current #3 is Indian defeat at turn 48 of King.
Why this defeat has such high score?

Comment: Probably all exploits/hacks :/

Comment: Option 1) a) cheating. or b) starting in a really favorable position with all techs already unlocked and immediately start building spaceship parts really fast. 2)Only domination victory allowed, and no enemy civs? This is all a guess though.

Comment: you can bet that these are hacks. You ever checked the GTA V Global leaderboards? Landing a chopper in 0.0 seconds seems hacked to me. Same case here.

Comment: look up the "ingame cheat engine" in civ 5 steam workshop, that should explain allot.